# TFS 2010 Get operation fails periodically on large files (> 1MB)

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Occasionally I get an error from my builds with the following error message:

> [Large File Name]: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> One or more errors occurred while performing a Get operation.

Everytime this happens, the file is always over 1MB in size.

The setup is TFS 2010 with a Build Agent that is a VMWare Virtual Machine running Windows Server 2003 R2.

As I mentioned earlier this does not happen all the time (maybe one out of ten times) so I hoping that there is a configuration setting I can alter to fix this.

Comment: Is the VM running locally or on a VMWare server somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

From you description above, I assume it is Windows Server **2008** R2, and not 2003. If so, this is a known issue with large files and you can find a blog entry describing the issue:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/taylaf/team-foundation-server-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)

Microsoft has released a QFE that you would need to apply to your App Server running TFS 2010. A link to request this QFE is in the blog entry, about in the middle.